# jQuery IF Value Equals Show Else Show

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to get the value from an input and if the value = 1,2,3... to show content else if value = 4,5,6... show other content. I almost had it working then something broke. I've been playing with this for ages. Could anyone have a quick look and point me where I've broken it.

```
var amount = $(".quantity-wrapper > .input-text").val();
    if(amount = '1') {
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
    }
    if(amount = '2'){
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
    } 
    if(amount = '3'){
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
    } 
    if(amount = '4'){
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-four-attendees').show();
    } 
    if(amount = '5'){
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-four-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-five-attendees').show();
    }
    if(amount = '6'){
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-four-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-five-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-six-attendees').show();
    }
    if(amount = '7'){
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-four-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-five-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-six-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-seven-attendees').show();
    }
    if(amount = '8'){
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-four-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-five-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-six-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-seven-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-eight-attendees').show();
    }
    if(amount = '9'){
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-four-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-five-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-six-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-seven-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-eight-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-nine-attendees').show();
    }
    if(amount = '10'){
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-four-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-five-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-six-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-seven-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-eight-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-nine-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-ten-attendees').show();
    }
    if(amount = '11'){
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-four-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-five-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-six-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-seven-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-eight-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-nine-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-ten-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-eleven-attendees').show();
    }
    if(amount = '12'){
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-four-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-five-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-six-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-seven-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-eight-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-nine-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-ten-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-eleven-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-twelve-attendees').show();
    }
```

Comment: = assigns, == equals, === strict equals. use ===

Comment: What they (^^^ vvv) said. Also, you could probably make that code *much* shorter if you used numeric identifiers (rather than the word "one", etc).

Comment: You've been clearly taking the wrong approach with this code. It could probably be refactored easily into a couple of lines, with much better maintainability.

Comment: No you wouldn't, because `(amount = '1')` ends up evaluating to `1`, which is truthy.

Comment: FYI this code really sucks. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(amount = '1') // it is assigning not the comparision
```

Correct way for comaprision

```
if(amount === '1')
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something simple. I had it working but with all the copy and pasting it forgot the most simplest thing. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

```
if(amount = '8'){  // you forget ==
```

change in

```
if(amount == '8'){
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have pointed out you should use a comparison operator, but how about reducing that ugly and repetitive code. You would need to change your markup so it ends up generating:

`product-addon-1-attendee`
`product-addon-2-attendee`
`product-addon-n-attendee`

```
// Get the amount value as a number
var amount = parseInt($(".quantity-wrapper > .input-text").val(), 10) || 0;

for (var i = 0; i < amount; ++i) {
    $('.product-addon-' + (i + 1) + '-attendee').show();
}
```

Comment: +1 in my eyes this should be the correct answer , and ppl should learn how to code smarter !

Answer (score 2):

*Note: considering your elements are ordered 1 through 12*

To shorten the code very much you can use :lt .and select with *.

```
   $('[class*="product-addon-"]:lt('+(amount)+')').show();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LxS6z/4/)

Otherwise another way of doing this is changing the class on all elements to `product-addon-anttendee`

```
<div class="product-addon-attendee">1</div>
<div class="product-addon-attendee">2</div>
```

and using this code

```
$('.product-addon-attendee:lt('+amount+')').show();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LxS6z/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your equal sign `'='` to `'=='` or `'==='` which will compare and not assign.
Also for your code a better structure will be a `switch`, possibly with `for` loops. It will be easier to track and to debug if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Better option instead if statement:

```
var amount = $(".quantity-wrapper > .input-text").val();
switch (amount) {
    case ('1'):
        alert('1');
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        break;
    case ('2'):
        alert('2');
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        break;
    case ('3'):
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
        break;
    case ('4'):
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-four-attendees').show();
        break;
    case ('5'):
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-four-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-five-attendees').show();
        break;
    case ('6'):
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-four-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-five-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-six-attendees').show();
        break;
    case ('7'):
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-four-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-five-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-six-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-seven-attendees').show();
        break;
    case ('8'):
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-four-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-five-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-six-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-seven-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-eight-attendees').show();
        break;
    case ('9'):
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-four-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-five-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-six-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-seven-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-eight-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-nine-attendees').show();
        break;
    case ('10'):
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-four-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-five-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-six-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-seven-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-eight-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-nine-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-ten-attendees').show();
        break;
    case ('11'):
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-four-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-five-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-six-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-seven-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-eight-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-nine-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-ten-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-eleven-attendees').show();
        break;
    case ('12'):
        $('.product-addon-one-attendee').show();
        $('.product-addon-two-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-three-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-four-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-five-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-six-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-seven-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-eight-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-nine-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-ten-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-eleven-attendees').show();
        $('.product-addon-twelve-attendees').show();
        break;
}
```